# Debian network bridge stops working randomly

Tags: linux, debian, networking, bridge

I have a host with qemu and bridge (PC -> eth0 -> br0 -> VM):

```
brctl addbr br0;
ip link set link up br0;
ip link set dev br0 up
brctl addif br0 eth0; ip link set dev br0 up; ip link set link up br0;
```

At a random time the interface `eth0` stops working, however `br0` is still working! There are no logs or messages! :-(

Comment: look like to use /etc/network/interfaces solved

Comment: It sounds like you found the solution on your own? If so, please use the Answer box below so that future readers know what the solution was. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the file /etc/network/interfaces solved the issue.

Comment: How did using it solve the issue? Can you add something to your answer that could help future readers trying to deal with the same problem?